# ¿Por qué no me cumple la condición del bucle en JavaScript (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bucle-for, bucles, while

¡Hola! Quiero pedir un número y quiero dividirlo entre 20 hasta que el resultado sea menor a 100, y después mostrar el resultado. Usé *while* anteriormente, pero no logré implementarlo y pensé que si aplicaba *do-while* funcionaría.

```js
let number;
let division;

$("#btnIngresar").click(determinarResultado);
function determinarResultado(){
    number = Number($("#txtNumber").val());
    if(number > 2000){
        do{
            division = number / 20;
            division++;
        }while(division < 100);
    }else{
        alert("¡Ingrese un número mayor a 2000!");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <label for="txtNumber">Número:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtNumber">
    <input type="button" value="Ingresar" id="btnIngresar">
    <p id="pResultado"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let number;
let division;

$("#btnIngresar").click(determinarResultado);
function determinarResultado(){
    number = Number($("#txtNumber").val());
    if(number > 2000){
        do{
            division = number / 20;
            number = division;
        }while(division > 100);
        console.log(division);
    }else{
        alert("¡Ingrese un número mayor a 2000!");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <label for="txtNumber">Número:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtNumber">
    <input type="button" value="Ingresar" id="btnIngresar">
    <p id="pResultado"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo único que estaba mal era tu condición, en la que en vez de colocar un simbolo `>` colocaste un `<`, el problema es que recuerda que el ciclo seguira corriendo hasta que la condicion deje de cumplirse, y no alrevez, por lo que el ciclo estaba haciendo lo contrario a lo que realmente deseabas.

Entonces lo primero que debes hacer es cambiar el signo `<` por `>` en la condición del `while`:

```
while(division > 100);
```

Lo segundo a tener en cuenta es que pese a que tu cambias `division` en cada iteracion, esto puede resultar en problemas de loop infinito (lo probe y me paso).

Asi que otra cosa que debes cambiar es esta parte de aqui:

```
do{
   division = number / 20;
   division++;
}
```

Donde lo que deberias tener enrealidad es esto de aquí:

```
do{
   division = number / 20;
   number = division;
}
```

Esto dividira tu variable `division` en 20 unidades por cada iteracion, y luego le asignamos a `number` el resultado, para poder ir dividiendo entre 20 y 20 en cada iteracion.

Comment: Otra cosa... dices que hasta que el resultado sea menor a cien, pero no se si deseas excluir el 100, así que si deseas excluir el 100 la condición no deberá ser > si no >=.

Comment: Estaba escribiendo justo lo mismo, buena respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que debes tomar en cuenta es que en la división luego de la asignación del resultado le estas sumando 1 (los ++ significan +1), entonces aunque la primera división se haga correcta le estas cambiando el resultado con ese ++, luego debes tener en cuenta que en tu segunda iteración el criterio de comparación debe ser el resultado de la división y no el numero inicial, por ello asigna el resultado de la división a numero, me tomé la libertad de cambiarlo a un while para ahorrar codigo pero el funcionamiento seria el mismo.

```js
let number = 0;
let division = 0;

$("#btnIngresar").click(determinarResultado);

function determinarResultado(){
    number = Number($("#txtNumber").val());
    if(number > 2000){
        while(number > 100)
        {
            number = number / 20;
            division = number;
        }
         console.log(division);
    }else{
        alert("¡Ingrese un número mayor a 2000!");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <label for="txtNumber">Número:</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtNumber">
    <input type="button" value="Ingresar" id="btnIngresar">
    <p id="pResultado"></p>
</body>
</html>
```